# ubuntu 13.10 gnome3-next 404 Not Found

Tags: gnome

I've upgraded from ubuntu 13.04 (Gnome) to 13.10 (Gnome) but after that I have added the repository of gnome next

```
ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
```

and make a refresh of repositories receive this error:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-ext/dists//ubuntu/saucy/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

someone knows why?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your PPA info,

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-ext/dists//ubuntu/saucy/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Find the bolded part in whatever file you put that line in and correct it. Alternatively, just comment out the line (with a `#` in front) and use the command below.

In future, to add launchpad PPA's, you should use the `add-apt-repository` command, not editing `sources.list`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
```

Comment: thanks minerz029. I don't why, but now it works